# gcloud suddenly lost valid credentials

Tags: gcloud

I have no idea what is going on, but essentially this is what happened:

I was working on some gcloud commands, and I impersonated a SA by using:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token \                                                           
  --impersonate-service-account sa@blah.com | docker login \
  -u oauth2accesstoken \
  --password-stdin https://us-east1-docker.pkg.dev
```

I then pushed a container into artifact registry and nothing went wrong.

Somehow, when I tried to re-run the above command, it told me that:

> ERROR: (gcloud.auth.print-access-token) Your current active account [ ] does not have any valid credentials

I think the ONLY valid response is: What the hell is going on? There is no change of ANYTHING (network, VPN, user, whatever). And the only thing I can do is to `gcloud auth login` again and again. I also used `gcloud auth login myaccount@company.com` to confirm that I AM using my account.

What can I do? It's already voodoo enough for me.

Comment: Possibly disk/file corruption so that `gcloud` is unable to persist credentials locally. When the error arises, can you `gcloud config get account`? `gcloud auth list`? Are you able to run any other `gcloud` commands that require credentials, e.g. `gcloud projects list`?

Comment: Typically I use `gcloud auth application-default login` and `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`. However, I think your actual problem is a transient issue at Google. Can you retry again using both methods?

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin yeah I can do that and I can also run other gcloud commands (at least the ones that I ran). BTW I found a way to go around so this is probably not a issue.